# How to convert an HTML file with content folder to a self-contained HTML file?

Tags: html

How do I convert an HTML file with content folder to a self-contained HTML file which can be viewed from anywhere with its images etc.

How can it be done so that it's also editable and stays self-contained, post-edit?

I basically need to make HTML file based documentation which can be viewed from anywhere. Unfortunately it HAS to be HTML, otherwise I would have made PDFs

Comment: Please add more information, I'm not quite sure what the question is. Images, examples, code are all welcome. HTML _can_ be viewed from any browser. So, what exactly are you looking to do? Maybe you mean "Inline CSS"? https://www.codecademy.com/articles/html-inline-styles

Answer (score 10):

You can use `pandoc`, it has an option to create self-contained html files https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--self-contained.

If you start with `html`, this is the command.

```
pandoc in.html --self-contained -o out.html
```

This tool can do *a lot* more things, for example, you can also generate `html` from markdown files or generate `pdf`s instead.

Comment: this method does not preserve styles

Comment: As @AntoineGallix points out, pandoc creates a self-contained html while at the same time silently ignores all CSS styles. In other words, totally useless except in some rare edge cases.

Comment: However, if you are lucky and haveing just a single CSS doing all styling you may go ahead with `pandoc in.html -c style.css --self-contained -o out.html` which eventually does what everyone expects.

Comment: In any other case, you could also just concatenate all the `css` files together into one, right? Isn't that how `css` works?

Answer (score 5):

The most direct way is to convert all asset urls to [`data:` urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). (There are online coverters available that will take a provided asset and produce a `data:` url from it.)

A possibly simpler way is to convert image and font urls to `data:` urls while instead inlining scripts and css.

---

**Edit:** Possibly of interest: [inliner](https://github.com/remy/inliner), a Node utility for doing this kind of thing. "Turns your web page to a single HTML file with everything inlined". Also performs a number of minifying optimizations.

Comment: Hm.  I tried `inliner` but it was giving me 404 errors when I tried a URL that had spaces in it, even though the spaces were converted to %20.  This URL in particular:  https://qrc.depaul.edu/StudyGuide2009/Notes/Savings%20Accounts/Compound%20Interest.htm

Comment: inliner did not get updated since 7 years, I'd consider removing it from the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you're envisioning, but HTML was never meant to be fully self-contained. There may be some loopholes that allow it in the end, but to my knowledge there are no premade tools that do this 'conversion'.
It would require the following things:

- Converting all linked style sheets and scripts to inline style sheets and scripts. This means that whenever there's a `<script src="http://url.to/foo.js"></script>` you'll have to download foo.js and include it as such: `<script type="text/javascript"> [this is the content of foo.js] </script>`. Something similar applies to CSS and other linked source files.
- Downloading all linked media (images mostly, I presume) and converting them to blobs (a service that provides you with a base64 blob you can use within a HTML file is https://www.base64-image.de/). This means replacing `<img src="http://url.to/image.jpg" />` with `<img src="data:image/png;base64,[converted image data goes here] />`.
  So there's gonna be some manual labour involved there, but it probably can be done (almost) fully.

Possibly there's a way to accomplish what you're wanting to do another way though, what exactly is your reason for wanting this?

Comment: i have accessed documentation that is of html file with text and images ...and those files we we could just email each other and still work.... granted it was document from a previous software vendor, but it still works. THATS what I m basing it off of.

Comment: I see. Then what I'm proposing above probably works best, though it is a bit of work. 
You could also convert it to PDF and then to a Word document (or directly to Word, though I'm not aware of a converter that does just that), but then it won't be HTML (though you could put it in Google Docs then, or something alike).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option: write your documentation in markup, then use a tool such as "Marked 2" (http://marked2app.com) to convert to **self-contained** html. Works slick. Plus you can go back and edit the markup any time you need to update your documentation, then simply re-export your html file.